# How can I show only the element associated with a clicked button?

Tags: reactjs

I have more than one button which written in array object (name, age). I would like to show only the (age) element of the clicked button

I would like to show only the (age) element of the clicked button, but it show age of all button instead

```
const App = () => {
  const [showAge, setShowAge] = useState(false);
  const people = [
    {
      name: "Jeje",
      age: 4,
    },
    {
      name: "Nene",
      age: 5,
    },
    {
      name: "Tom",
      age: 8,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
        {people.map((person) => (
          <>
            <div onClick={() => setShowAge(!showAge)}>
              <p data-id={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
            </div>
            {showAge && <p className="px-3">{person.age}</p>}
          </>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store only the selected index in state instead.

```js
const [idx, setIdx] = useState();
```

```js
{people.map((person, i) => (
  <>
    <div onClick={() => setIdx(i)}>
      <p data-id={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
    </div>
    {idx === i && <p className="px-3">{person.age}</p>}
  </>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [showAge, setShowAge] = useState(false);
```

```
<div>
  {people.map((person) => (
    <>
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          setShowAge(!showAge);
          setNameToBeShow(person.age);
        }}
      >
        <p data-id={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
      </div>
      {nameToBeShow != 0 && person.age===nameToBeShow ?  <p className="px-3">{nameToBeShow}</p> : ''}
    </>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).